# required field check is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
 <form id="form" method="get"   onsubmit="return postToGoogle();" action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="off" required>
   <div id="result">
        <input id="nameField" name="entry.1029693185" placeholder="Ad" type="text" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" class=" feedback-input"><br><br>
        <input id="surnameField" name="entry.504917646" placeholder="Soyad" type="text" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" class="feedback-input"> <br><br>
        <input id="emailField" name="entry.1481216637" placeholder="E-Mail"  type="email" required  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" class=" feedback-input"> <br><br>
        <input id="mobField" name="entry.925328256" placeholder="Firma Adı" type="text" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" class="feedback-input"> <br><br>
        <input id="depField" name="entry.50062144" placeholder="Çalıştığınız Departman" type="text" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" class=" feedback-input">

        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="qdrm" id="qdrm">
        <input type="submit" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align: center;" onclick="giris();" value="Sınava Başla" id="button-blue" />
        <div class="ease"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRİPT**

```
function giris() {
    if (nameField.value != "" && surnameField.value != "" && emailField.value != "" &&  mobField.value != "" && depField.value != "") {

        function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
            var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

            function twoDigits(n) {
                return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
            }

            function updateTimer() {
                msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
                if (msLeft < 1000) {

                    displayScore2();
                    postToGoogle(); {

                        $('#end').hide();
                        $('#messagetime').show();
                        $('#quiz').hide();
                        $('#countdown').hide();
                        $('#description').hide();
                        $('#next').hide();
                    }


                } else {
                    time = new Date(msLeft);
                    hours = time.getUTCHours();
                    mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
                    element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
                    setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
                }
            }

            element = document.getElementById(elementName);
            endTime = (+new Date) + 100 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
            updateTimer();
        }

        countdown("tiles", 10, 0);

    } else {
        alert("Boş Alanları Doldurunuz!");
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('messagend').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('form-div').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('qdrm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('txt1').style.display = 'inline'; // ikinci sayfa 
    document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none';

}
```

**free space checking is not working properly and i'm new to this please help about it  I can post all the codes if you want.
**

Comment: What do you mean by Free space checking?

Comment: your form will submit, regardless of the code in `giris` - also, you have `onsubmit="return postToGoogle();"` and a call to `postToGoogle` inside `giris` function - are you sure that's right?

Comment: I did a test at my delivery company but the text control is not working properly I want to do this

Comment: I send data to excel with postToGoggle with google forms